# Efficient way to select records with children?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ to SQL query that is something like the following...

```
return from parent in Context.Parents
       where 
       (
          (parent.SomeProperty != null && parent.SomeProperty != "")
          ||
          (Context.Childs.Count(c => c.ParentID == parent.ID && c.Type == "SomeType") > 0)
       )
       select parent
```

The idea is that I want to find all the parent records that have either got a value for "SomeProperty" or that have some child records of type "SomeType".

The problem is that the query is timing out.  Is there a quicker (but still easy to read) way of doing the same thing?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I would recommend logging the generated SQL and then trying to run that manually to further determine the performance bottleneck(s). It may be a bum-generated query or it may be a lack of crucial index, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Any()` instead of `Count()`:

```
return from parent in Context.Parents
       where 
       (
          (parent.SomeProperty != null && parent.SomeProperty != "")
          ||
          Context.Childs.Any(c => c.ParentID == parent.ID 
                                  && c.Type == "SomeType")
       )
       select parent;
```

In Linq to SQL `Count(<some condition>)` is translated into:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE <some condition>
```

query which requires iterating over all rows in the database to find the count.

In Linq to SQL `Any(<some condition>)` is translated to a

```
EXISTS (.. <some condition>)
```

subquery which allows short circuiting the result once the first match is found.

The exact SQL mapping can be found in this SO answer: [query result what should i use Count() or Any()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856965/linq-to-sql-query-result-what-should-i-use-count-or-any/2857117#2857117)

Comment: Easier to read for sure, does this actually improve the performance?

Comment: @Bobby: It should, as `Any()` gets translated to `EXISTS` but `Count()` has to aggregate an entire set.

Comment: @Bobby Borszich: Conceptually yes, since `Any()` can short circuit after finding the first match but `Count()` has to go over all rows. Practically it hugely depends on the actual data.

Comment: @Bobby Borszich I would imagine so because `Any` is allowed to succeed-fast (when the *first*) match is found. `Count` must iterate through the *entire* sequence to count matches. However, since this is LINQ2SQL, have to take the generated SQL into account as well to see if there is anything tricky going on.

Comment: There's an SO answer with the actual generated SQL here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856965/linq-to-sql-query-result-what-should-i-use-count-or-any/2857117#2857117

Comment: @BrokenGlass Now, comparing the Execution Plans / Optimizations (the SQL engine could technically turn a COUNT() > 1 into an EXISTS or otherwise succeed-fast when the count limit was reached) -- I have no idea what kind of tricks go on at that level ;) In Any case, I find `Any()` more clear *and* it translates better to "normal" LINQ.

Comment: Using Any() seems to have done the trick.  The query is no longer timing out and is indeed much quicker.  Many thanks for you help